# UICollectionView Scroll Performance Horrible

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, smooth-scrolling

I have around 14 items in my collectionView and the scrolling is not smooth at all. I am using auto layout (my constraints don't log errors), and I am using the cornerRadius property (it's a messaging app).

I've tried analyzing it using the Time Profiler instrument, and this was what I see when I scroll:

[image]

Unfortunately "Reveal in Xcode" is grayed out, so I can't see exactly what line is taking forever. I am calculating the size of each item though. I'm wondering what the huge 9377 ms delay could be? I'm not using ordered sets if I recall correctly.

Here's my `cellForItemAtIndexpath` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Define Message
    Message *message = (Message *)[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    //Check Message Type
    switch (message.type) {
        case MessageTypeText: {

            //Initialize Cell
            TextMessageItem *cell = (TextMessageItem *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kTextMessageItemIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            //Return Cell
            return cell;

            break;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Here's how i'm calculating the height:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Retrieve the right message
    Message *message = (Message *)[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Check Message Type
    switch (message.type) {
        case MessageTypeText: {

            //Create a temporary cell to get the correct size
            TextMessageItem *tempCell = [[TextMessageItem alloc] init];

            //Configure the cell
            [self collectionView:collectionView configureTextCell:tempCell atIndexPath:indexPath];

            CGSize s = [tempCell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh verticalFittingPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];

            //Return Content Size
            return CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.bounds.size.width, s.height);

            break;
        }
    }

    //Return
    return CGSizeMake(0, 0);
}
```

My `WillDisplayCell` Method:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Retrieve message from our array of messages
    Message *message = (Message *)[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Check Message Type
    switch (message.type) {
        case MessageTypeText: {

            //Cast Cell
            TextMessageItem *textItem = (TextMessageItem *)cell;
            [self collectionView:collectionView configureTextCell:textItem atIndexPath:indexPath];

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And lastly, this is my custom `configureTextCell` method:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView configureTextCell:(TextMessageItem *)item atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //Retrieve Message
    Message *message = (Message *)[self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    //Display Timestamp if Needed
    [self displayTimestampForItemIfNeeded:item atIndex:indexPath.item];

    //Update Top Message Padding Based On Who Sent The Previous Message
    [self updateDistanceFromPreviousMessageForItem:item atIndex:indexPath.item];

    //Display Delivery Status if Needed (e.g. Delivered)
    [self displayDeliveryStatusForItemIfNeeded:item atIndex:indexPath.item];

    //Set Message
    [item setMessage:message];
}
```

Comment: Could it be that my `cellForItemAtIndexpath` isn't implemented correctly? My `UICollectionViewCell` subclass is done programmatically (no storyboard or xib files), and I'm noticing that on initial load, its `initWithFrame` method is being called for each item in my self.messages array. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Using corner radii or layer masks is a good way to kill scrolling performance as compositing is way more expensive. Instead you could use a CAShapeLayer with rounded corners to back your view or as a sublayer of your view. Or you could draw your content with rounded corners into an image that you add to your view. You should also avoid having your view clip-to-bounds. 
(I'm typing this on my phone away from my computer so I can't paste in any snippets right now.)

Comment: Thanks Mustang. Let me try making a few changes that you're suggesting and see if there's any noticeable difference.

Comment: I tried what you're suggesting and although it does help a bit, it is still noticeably laggy. The time profiler operation dropped from 9377ms to 8800ms. So the real question is... what could possibly be taking 8800ms? This only shows when I scroll, not on viewDidLoad if that helps narrow it down.

Comment: When I get a second, I'll look more closely at your code. Another thing you never want to do is change constraints at prepareForReuse time or dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier time. Set these up at init time.

Comment: How do I know if I'm doing that when it's preparing for reuse? I' currently doing that at willDisplayCell is that okay?